# How operator<< works with manipulator functions

Tags: c++, stl

In C++ is possible to write code like this:

```
cout << std::endl;
```

where, std::endl is a function that will be called with cout as a parameter. I'm wondering is it special feature of << and >> operators or there is a generic rule that allows to do same thing with other operators (for example with +)?

Comment: Are you sure that's the way it works?  I'd expect `cout::operator<<` to be called.

Comment: @MakrRansom it is called,but `std::endl` itself is a function template

Comment: Warning:  once you start going down the path of operating overloading, you may find yourself overindulging and using them everywhere.  Although you may find them fun, your coworkers may think you've gone crazy.  At the bottom of that path you'll find the likes of [Boost Spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) or [Boost Assignment](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) -- very cool, yes, but not what I'd call idiomatic C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing really special about this.  [`std::ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is simply overloaded to accept various types in input.

In the case of manipulator functions, `operator<<` is overloaded to accept certain types of function pointers as input by default:

```cpp
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );

basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );

basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

And then the implementations of those overloads just call whatever function is passed in to them, specifying `*this` as the function's input parameter, eg:

```cpp
basic_ostream& basic_ostream::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) )
{
    (*func)(*this);
    return *this;
}

basic_ostream& basic_ostream::operator<<(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&))
{
    (*func)(*this);
    return *this;
}

basic_ostream& basic_ostream::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&))
{
    (*func)(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

Thus `cout << std::endl;` is simply calling `cout.operator<<(std:endl);`, where [`std::endl()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) matches the 3rd overload above:

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

In the case of the stream manipulator functions in the `<iomanip>` header, the manipulators that do not take any input parameters from user's code (ie `std::boolalpha`, `std::showbase`,  etc) are usually implemented as standalone functions that match one of the overloads above, and thus DO get passed the `ostream`/`istream` directly as a parameter.  However, the manipulators that take input parameters from user code (ie `std::resetiosflags()`, `std::setbase()`, etc) are defined to return "unspecified" (ie implementation-defined) types, where their implementations define additional overloads of `operator<<` and `operator>>` for those types so they can receive the `ostream`/`istream` to manipulate, respectively.

For example: `std::fill` might be implemented something like this:

```cpp
template< class CharT >
struct fill_t { CharT ch; };

template< class CharT >
fill_t setfill( CharT c )
{
    return fill_t<CharT>{c};
}

template< class CharT >
basic_ostream& operator<<(basic_ostream& out, const fill_t &in)
{
    out.fill(in.ch);
    return out;
}
```

Thus `cout << setfill(' ')` calls the equivalent of `fill_t tmp = setfill(' '); operator<<(cout, tmp);`

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special going on here.  `std::istream` and `std::ostream` have overloads for the `operator >>` and `operator <<` respectively in the form of

```
basic_istream& operator>>( std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );
basic_istream& operator>>( std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );
basic_istream& operator>>( basic_istream& (*func)(basic_istream&) );

basic_ostream& operator<<( std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );
basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );
basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

that allow the class to take a function pointer as the right hand side of the operator.  When doing

```
cout << std::endl;
```

`std::endl` decays into a function pointer and the correct overload is called.  You can do this with any operator for any type you have.

---

If you do plan to do this, think about the principal of least surprise, i.e don't use a common syntax that has a completely different meaning and use that as your custom overload.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   int f = 0;
};

Foo operator+(Foo foo, int (*function)())
{
   return {foo.f + function()};
}

int one()
{
   return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
   Foo foo {10};
   std::cout << (foo+one).f << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
11
```